# Scroll to with fixed nav hiding content

Tags: jquery, scroll

Quick question. I have implemented a scroll to method to scroll to my divs with that particular id from the navigation. As my navigation bar is fixed its scrolling to far down.. how do i offset so that it scrolls to the correct postion.. Up loaded some images and the js code..

hope you can help...

This is what ive got...

[image]

and this is what i want....

[image]

js file..

```
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem once, so i used this function:

```
var scrolldown = function(item, tuner) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(item).offset().top - tuner
            }, 2000, 'easeOutCirc');
    }
```

Where item is the id to scroll to, and tuner is the value in pixels to adjust the end position of the scroll.

You can use it like:

```
$('#id-of-nav').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    scrolldown("#id-of-target", "150")
});
```

This is the site where you can see it in action: https://www.tabapp.com/

Ofcourse you can erase the animation.